# Question about equivalent equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am solving equations with radicals using this substitution:

$f(x)^{\frac{1}{3}}+g(x)^{\frac{1}{3}}=h(x)$

$f(x)+g(x)+3(f(x)g(x))^{\frac{1}{3}}(f(x)^{\frac{1}{3}}+g(x)^{\frac{1}{3}})=h(x)^{{3}}$

Now I substitute the expression $f(x)^{\frac{1}{3}}+g(x)^{\frac{1}{3}}$  with $h(x)$. Why after this substitution the new equation is not equivalent to the original??

Comment: In what sense it's not equivalent?

Comment: After the substitution you get another equation, and has to be another, because you cubed everything. I don't understand what is your doubt.

Comment: When power both sides of equation to n-th power and n is odd, then the resulting equation is equivalent to the initial!

Comment: In what sense is equivalent? What do you mean by "equivalent" equations?

Comment: Have same solutions

Answer (score 2):

To make things clear, let's denote $a = f(x), b = g(x), c = h(x)$, then

$$a^{1/3}+b^{1/3} = c$$

$$(a^{1/3}+b^{1/3})^3 = a + 3a^{2/3}b^{1/3} + 3a^{1/3}b^{2/3} + b = a+3a^{1/3}b^{1/3}(a^{1/3} + b^{1/3}) + b =$$
$$= a+3a^{1/3}b^{1/3}c + b = a+3(ab)^{1/3}c + b =c^3.$$

Therefore
$$(a+3(ab)^{1/3}c + b)^{1/3} = c = a^{1/3} + b^{1/3}$$

or

$$ a+ b =c^3-3(ab)^{1/3}c = c(c^2-3(ab)^{1/3}).$$

Because you are mixing the terms, you can get some messy equations, but it does not mean they are wrong.

Comment: All this is correct but it's still not clear why. Logic says it shouldn't be so.

Comment: Logic says it SHOULD BE. All this is correct because all steps are logically true.